# Maximal set of 3-element subsets with empty or singleton intersections

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$,

and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a set of 3-element subsets of $X$ such that

$\mathrm{card}\,(A\cap B)\leq 1$ for all $A\in\mathcal{C}$ and $B\in\mathcal{C}$.

What is the maximum of $\mathrm{card}\,\mathcal{C}$ ?

I have found $\mathcal{C}$ with 12 subsets of $X$:

1, 2, 3

4, 5, 6

7, 8, 9

1, 4, 7

2, 5, 8

3, 6, 9

1, 5, 9

2, 6, 7

3, 4, 8

3, 5, 7

1, 6, 8

2, 4, 9

But is this example of $\mathcal{C}$ the maximal or not?

It is funny that the last 6 subsets look like the Sarrus' rule for the determinant of the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{bmatrix}

Is it coincidence or not?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: We have ${9\choose 3}=84$ subsets, each of them might be included or not. So $2^{84}$ search is a way too large to compute. ${84\choose 13}$ is too large too. Any idea of a shorter search maybe?)

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955318/creating-combinations-that-have-no-more-one-intersecting-element

Answer (score 1):

Note that each element $x \in X$ can appear in at most $4$ elements of $\mathcal{C}$, since if $A_1, \dots, A_n$ are the sets in $\mathcal{C}$ containing $x$, then $A_1 \setminus \{x\}, \dots, A_n \setminus \{x\}$ are disjoint sets of size $2$ in the $8$-element set $X \setminus \{x\}$. Then if we count the pairs $(x, A)$ of $x \in X$ and $A \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $x \in A$, there are at most $4|X| = 36$ such pairs (at most $4$ for each $x$), but on the other hand there are exactly $3|\mathcal{C}|$ such pairs, hence $3|\mathcal{C}| \leq 36$, and thus $|\mathcal{C}| \leq 12$.